# How to start Plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, plasma-5

I use Kubuntu 15.04. And my Plasma 5 crashed and not restarted. Rebooting didn't help. Now there are only windows. How can I start Plasma 5?

Comment: Take a look at this question over on [su]: http://superuser.com/questions/933890/how-do-i-restart-the-plasma-shell-in-kde5

Answer (score 5):

on Plasma 5 the command is `plasmashell`

Answer (score 0):

If only Plasma crashed, you can restart it by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, if you didn't assign another shortcut, and enter the following command:

```
plasma-desktop --replace
```

This will kill all remaining instances of Plasma and start a new one.

Comment: In the situation described by the OP, it's good to do that in the terminal and observe the output. If plasma does not start correctly, there typically is a reason that will be displayed. I myself several times run into a situation when plasma after crash will not want to start anymore since some old cash/lock files are present. In such situation , plasma might hang when starting and deleting plasma related config files will help.

Comment: plasma-desktop: command not found

Comment: Is it `plasma5-desktop`?

Comment: ....... Plasma 5

Comment: I know you're using Plasma 5, this was rather a suggestion for you to try than a question. I'm not using KDE as my main desktop, I only maintain one or two Kubuntu machines, so I am not omniscient.

Comment: This only worked on Plasma 4 series